# deviceManger.lockNow() is Not Working on some Device

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

I am working on Phone Lock from this [Reference](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1291/android_device_policy_administration_tutorial). Working well on my Samsung Tab 2. But when I run the Same Code On Nexus 2. It does not work .I have posted some Code below. 
It Logs `"DeviceAdminSample"  "Admin enable FAILED!"`. Any help will be Appreciated !!
Is there any Restriction on Nexus?

```
onCreate()
{
 deviceManger = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(  
                  Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);  
                activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(  
                  Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);  
                compName = new ComponentName(this, MyAdmin.class); 
}

private void EnableSetting() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager  
                 .ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);  
                        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,  
                                compName);  
                        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,  
                                "Additional text explaining why this needs to be added.");  
                        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_ENABLE);  
    }
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
         switch (requestCode) {  
             case RESULT_ENABLE:  
                 if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  
                     Log.i("DeviceAdminSample", "Admin enabled!");  
                 } else {  
                     Log.i("DeviceAdminSample", "Admin enable FAILED!");  
                 }  

         }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code for main Activity

```
public class LockerTest extends Activity {
    protected static final int REQUEST_ENABLE = 0;
    DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager;
    ComponentName adminComponent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(btnListener);

    }

    Button.OnClickListener btnListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adminComponent = new ComponentName(LockerTest.this, Darclass.class);
            devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

            if (!devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(adminComponent)) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, adminComponent);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE);
            } else {
                devicePolicyManager.lockNow();
            }

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (REQUEST_ENABLE == requestCode) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Create a new class - Darclass - code

```
import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver;

public class Darclass extends DeviceAdminReceiver{

}
```

Create a folder 'xml' in 'res'. Then create my_admin.xml file in 'xml' folder. Code for my_admin.xml. Note add this receiver after  and before

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        <limit-password />
        <watch-login />
        <reset-password />
        <force-lock />
        <wipe-data />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Finally add the receiver given bellow to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
            android:name=".Darclass"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/my_admin" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

It should work on your device.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. I am using that same Code. But its showing Log at `@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (REQUEST_ENABLE == requestCode) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }`..its going in this `else` condition..check my `onActivityResult`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.  It was because my ... block was outside of my  block in AndroidManifest.xml.  Worked perfectly when I moved the ... block, as shown here:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="MyDeviceAdminReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin" android:resource="@xml/device_admin_xml" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
                <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED" />
                <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```